# If $f\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}/(p)\colon M\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}/(p)\to N\otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z}/(p)$ is onto for all $p$, $f$ onto?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, abelian-groups

This lemma is used in a theorem I'm reading, with no proof.

> Suppose $f\colon M\to N$ is a morphism of free, finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. Then if $f\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ is surjective for all primes $p$, then $f$ is surjective itself.

The text says it is clear. Why is the lemma true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $N$ is finitely generated, we have an exact sequence

$$M\stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} N\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^k\times T\rightarrow 1$$

where $T$ is finite and $k \ge 0$. If $f$ is not surjective then either $k\ge 1$ or $T$ is nontrivial.

Since tensoring is right-exact, tensoring this sequence with $\mathbb{Z}/p$ gives:

$$M/pM\stackrel{f\otimes\mathbb{Z}/p}{\longrightarrow} N/pN\longrightarrow (\mathbb{Z}/p)^k\times T/pT\longrightarrow 1$$

If $k\ge 1$ (ie, $f(M)$ has infinite index in $N$), then and since $(\mathbb{Z}/p)$ is nontrivial for any $p$, we find that $f\otimes\mathbb{Z}/p$ is not surjective for any $p$.

If $T$ is nontrivial, then for any $p\mid |T|$, we find that $pT\subsetneq T$, so $T/pT$ is nontrivial. Thus, $f\otimes\mathbb{Z}/p$ is not surjective for any $p\mid |T|$.

In either case there exist primes $p$ for which $f\otimes\mathbb{Z}/p$ is not surjective.

EDIT: At first I tried proving this via elementary means - ie, given preimages of $n\in N$ mod every prime, I tried to stitch them together to get a preimage of $n$ over $\mathbb{Z}$. While this must be possible, I couldn't divine a formula quickly. I guess the lesson here is - when dealing with modules (or in general working in any abelian category), exact sequences are your friend.

Comment: Thanks oxeimon, I take it $M\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}/(p)\cong M/pM$ since $pm\otimes 1=m\otimes p=0$ more or less? I've just never seen that isomorphism before but it makes sense.

Comment: @JoieHwang Yep exactly. For any $R$-module $M$, and $f\in R$, $M\otimes_R R/(f) = M/fM$. Once you think about it a bit it becomes pretty clear they're the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

> Let $R$ be a commutative unitary ring, $M$ an $R$-module, $N$ a *finitely generated* $R$-module, and $f:M\to N$ a homomorphism. Suppose that $\bar f:M/\mathfrak mM\to N/\mathfrak mN$ is surjective for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ of $R$. Then $f$ is surjective.

$f$ surjective $\Leftrightarrow$ $f_{\mathfrak m}:M_{\mathfrak m}\to N_{\mathfrak m}$ surjective for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ of $R$.

$\bar f$ surjective $\Leftrightarrow$ $\operatorname{Im}\bar f=N/\mathfrak mN$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\operatorname{Im}f+\mathfrak mN=N$ $\Rightarrow$ $\operatorname{Im}f_{\mathfrak m}+\mathfrak mN_{\mathfrak m}=N_{\mathfrak m}$.

Since $N_{\mathfrak m}$ is finitely generated, by Nakayama lemma we get $\operatorname{Im}f_{\mathfrak m}=N_{\mathfrak m}$, that is, $f_{\mathfrak m}$ is surjective.